# Do github traffic insights include visits to the raw versions of files?

Tags: github, traffic

I'm wondering whether the traffic insights are just for people visiting the main repo pages, or if they also include when people visit the raw version of a file?

Comment: GitHub's traffic insights typically include:


1. Clones: The number of times the repository is cloned.

2. Unique Cloners: The number of unique users who have cloned the repository.

3. Views: The number of times the repository is viewed.

4. Unique Visitors: The number of unique users who have viewed the repository.

These metrics are aggregated at the repository level and don't drill down to specific files or their raw version.